# Solve for $px + q \equiv 0\pmod r$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How would I solve for the following in general:

> $(px + q)\equiv 0 \pmod r$

For example,

> $ (2x + 1)=0 \pmod 7 $
>
> $x = 3, 10, 17, 24, \ldots $
>
> $(9y + 5)= 0 \pmod 3 $
>
> $y$ has no solution.

I came up with the answers through intuition, but is there an actual proof or formula that can solve for the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title is misleading: the % symbol is the modulus: it $(px + q) \mathbin{\%} r$ means the ***remainder*** after dividing $(px + q)$ by $r$. This can be expressed as equivalence modulo $r$.

E.g., your first equivalence reads:

$$2x + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 7 \iff 2x \equiv -1 \pmod 7 $$ $$\iff 2x \equiv 6 \pmod 7 \iff x \equiv 3 \pmod 7$$

So indeed, $x \in \{..., -4, 3, 10, 17, 24, ...\}$

---

For your second question: $(9y + 5) \mathbin{\%} 3 = 0$, we are interested in the remainder of $9y + 5$ when divided by $3$, and testing whether this remainder can be equal to $0$: Note that $3$ divides $9y$ for all values of $y$, but $3$ does not divide $5$: so $3$ cannot divide $9y + 5$ evenly, so it cannot hold. That is,

$$9y + 5 \equiv 0 \pmod 3 \iff 9y \equiv -5 \pmod 3 $$
$$\iff 9y \equiv 1 \pmod 3$$ which, as you note, *cannot hold* because $9y\equiv 0 \pmod 3$, that is, $9y$ is divisible by 3, whatever the value of $y$, and so there *cannot be* a remainder of $1$.

---

**Resources:**

- [**Modular Arithmetic**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), Wikipedia
- [**Congruences: Chapt. 2**](http://math453fall2008.wikidot.com/chapter-2) On-line "lecture" series of notes for seven lectures.

Comment: Thanks! Seems so obvious once you see the answer..

Comment: Edited the title to more accurately reflect the nature of the question.

Comment: Your welcome! Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Thanks @Willie, for the edit: I totally missed the % problem!